# Skip true option returns uninitialized state even if Im initializing the query in other hook

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I want to read the existing current data of a query without triggering it.

I have following component that uses the same hook with different properties:

```
const Deployment = ({
  environment
}) => {
  const valueWithSkipping = useDeployEnvironmentQuery(environment.name, { skip: true })
  const valueDefault = useDeployEnvironmentQuery(environment.name)
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Deployment</h2>
      <pre>
        <code>
          {JSON.stringify({ valueWithSkipping }, null, 2)}
          {JSON.stringify({ valueDefault }, null, 2)}
        </code>
      </pre>
    </>
  )
}
```

It prints following data:

```
{
  "valueWithSkipping": {
    "status": "uninitialized",
    "isUninitialized": true,
    "isLoading": false,
    "isSuccess": false,
    "isError": false,
    "isFetching": false
  }
}
{
  "valueDefault": {
    "status": "pending",
    "endpointName": "deployEnvironment",
    "requestId": "1WgRmoEoRVtyUOZObKNS1",
    "originalArgs": "env-name-1",
    "startedTimeStamp": 1658407995798,
    "isUninitialized": false,
    "isLoading": true,
    "isSuccess": false,
    "isError": false,
    "isFetching": true
  }
}
```

I want both to print the same since Im using the same arguments. Is it possible? Or Im missing something?

Comment: The `skip` argument is for avoiding the execution of that query, so, it will be uninitialized until `skip` evaluates to `false`. Even when you are referring to the same query, each time you call the hooks it have its own instance although share the same cache with other calls

Comment: Thanks. I think I have to use `useQueryState`

Comment: For a query to have data it must be executed at least once. Whenever you call the same query with the same arguments (within certain time lapse) you will receive the cached response, not actually reaching the server again. If you don't want to use the query hook at all then you can use a selector to extract data from cache, but then maybe it is not updated. My advise, call the hook, if the cache is outdated the query will reach the server otherwise it will response with the cached response.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution using `useQueryState`:

```
const Deployment = ({
  environment
}: {
  environment: Environment
}) => {
  const valueWithSkipping = api.endpoints.deployEnvironment.useQueryState(environment.name)
  const valueDefault = useDeployEnvironmentQuery(environment.name)
  return (
    <>
      <h2>Deployment</h2>
      <pre>
        <code>
          {JSON.stringify({ valueWithSkipping }, null, 2)}
          {JSON.stringify({ valueDefault }, null, 2)}
        </code>
      </pre>
    </>
  )
}
```